# bcp does not work in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, export, backup

I am trying to export some tables to a file as a backup.

To do this I am using the `bcp` utility from SQL Server. I work on SQL Server 2008, but despite the fact it should theoretically work, when I write on the SQL editor window it doesn't seem to recognize the command...

Does somebody have any command to do backup from a table? This way I could create a procedure to do this massively.

Comment: Can you show your command and are you getting any error? Also, what version of 2008 are you using? R2, Express?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is a command line tool. You run it in the [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), not in SQL Editor. You can, at least in theory, run it from inside the SQL using [xp_cmdshell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) but it might not be enabled for you, and it's usually a lot easier to handle errors etc. when you do it for example in a .bat file and not try to do it inside the database.

Comment: Ohh ok, i did not know that it is a command line tool. I will try it in a .bat file.